# Are there any online course/video lectures available on Density functional theory?

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request

Please mention good online video lectures on theoretical foundations and practical implementation of DFT.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I like your question since the answers could become a valuable source for others in the future, but "good" might be too opinion-based. Could you be more specific about what kind of response you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removed good from the question

Comment: I see there's 2 close votes at the moment. However, it is almost the same as this question which has 21 upvotes and 19 stars: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/are-there-any-organised-resources-available-from-where-i-can-begin-my-quantum-co

Comment: Or this one, also with 21 upvotes: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/currently-what-are-the-best-structured-courses-available-online-on-quantum-comp

Comment: Or this one, with 25 upvotes: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/introductory-material-for-quantum-machine-learning

Comment: Great question - very useful.

Comment: Content describing the practical aspects of writing a DFT implementation is difficult to find in my experience. One example of an open source code is els: https://github.com/ElectronicStructureLibrary/esl-demo

Comment: @Alex: I think you should post it as a question and answer yourself. SE encourages that. You can even explain a bit and will be very useful for everyone

Comment: Atleast you should post it as an answer here with some explanation

Answer (score 14):

**1. [Online course on Computational Materials Physics](http://compmatphys.epotentia.com/) by [Prof. Stefaan Cottenier](https://molmod.ugent.be/members/stefaan-cottenier)**

> All content is offered via prerecorded videos. Each video comes with a task, and after submitting the task there is in many cases either automated feedback or peer feedback. At any other time of the year, you can still study this course in a self-paced way. There is the opportunity to be part of a team to work on a project. The course is free of cost and open to anyone. Emphasis is on conceptual understanding and hands-on training, not on mathematical theory.

**2. [An Introduction to Density Functional Theory for Experimentalists](https://www.paradim.org/cu_ss_2018) by [Prof. Feliciano Giustino](https://www.oden.utexas.edu/people/1669/) during DFT Summer School 2018 at Cornell University**

> The goal of this Summer School is to introduce experimentalists to density-functional theory calculations and first-principles materials modelling. This course answers the basic questions: “Can DFT help me with my experimental problem? Which  materials  properties  can  be predicted  and  how reliable are the results? How difficult would it be to run the calculation that I need? Can I do this on my own or I better seek for help from the theory group next door?”. By the end of the school the participants will be able to perform basic DFT calculations in complete autonomy, and will have a better understanding of the current literature on atomistic modelling using DFT. The course is articulated along three parallel tracks: theory lectures, practical lectures, and hands-on sessions.

**3. [Advanced Workshop on High-Performance & High-Throughput Materials Simulations using Quantum ESPRESSO | (smr 3102), Trieste, January 16 - 31, 2017](https://www.materialscloud.org/learn/sections/lfYatW/hpc-and-high-throughput-materials-modeling-ictp-trieste-2017)**

Comment: Feliciano's summer school content can also be found in his book "Materials Modelling Using Density Functional Theory: Properties and Predictions", which was specifically written with materials scientists in mind.

Answer (score 14):

Thomas has listed some great resources. Let me add some more, mostly materials science-related ones:

NOMAD has regular workshops, "Hands-on DFT and beyond", and the recordings from 2017, Berlin are uploaded to Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbgFiRV2JFy-VQ3D6cJjn5jkXmAsjQPiT
Slides of the more recent workshops can be found

- Barcelona (2019): https://th.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/meetings/dft-workshop-2019/index.php?n=Meeting.Program
- Peking (2018): https://th.fhi-berlin.mpg.de/sitesub/meetings/dft-workshop-2018/index.php?n=Meeting.Program

Kieron Burke has several good links on his lab page, including a CECAM lecture series from 2017, "Teaching the Theory in Density Functional Theory"  (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfLssAro7SMxgaeKTNFFeeA/feed)

- Burke group page: https://dft.uci.edu/learnDFT.php

Answer (score 9):

I have found some interesting lectures about DFT in general that could be useful for you:

[**2017 Hands-on Workshop Density-Functional Theory and Beyond**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbgFiRV2JFy-VQ3D6cJjn5jkXmAsjQPiT)  - Humboldt University Berlin, Germany.

[**Teaching the Theory in Density Functional Theory**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfLssAro7SMxgaeKTNFFeeA/feed)

[**Putting the Theory Back in Density Functional Theory**](http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/programs/summer-schools/putting-the-theory-back-in-density-functional-theory/?tab=schedule) - Institute for Pure & Applied Mathematics (UCLA)