# Is there any recent beginner's reference on materials informatics?

Tags: reference-request, materials-informatics

I wonder if anyone might save me several clicks and hours of scrolling and point me to a good recent survey/book on materials informatics to get me acquainted with the field?

Comment: There is a similar question/answer here (https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/123/are-there-any-online-course-video-lectures-available-on-density-functional-theor).

Comment: @AnibalBezerra that question is for DFT, does the answer have anything to do with Materials Informatics?

Comment: @NikeDattani, to me it does! I do consider DFT as Materials Informatics...

Comment: @AnibalBezerra Informatics usually refers to tools for big data processing and interpretation, rather than the underlying method used to produce the data. You could apply informatics techniques to the results of many DFT calculations, but I wouldn't consider DFT itself a form of informatics.

Answer (score 6):

Here you can find some materials (article reviews & books) about Materials Informatics:

[Perspective: Materials informatics and big data: Realization of the “fourth paradigm” of science in materials science.](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4946894)

[Machine learning in materials informatics: recent applications and prospects.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-017-0056-5)

[Materials Informatics: Methods, Tools, and Applications.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Materials+Informatics%3A+Methods%2C+Tools%2C+and+Applications-p-9783527341214)

[Materials informatics](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1369-7021(05)71123-8).

[Informatics for Materials Science and Engineering.Chapter 1 - Materials Informatics: An Introduction.](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-394399-6.00001-1)

Comment: Thank you, those are exactly what I could hope to get!  I also got one recommended from elsewhere, but it is in Japanese - in case someone finds it useful:  https://pub.nikkan.co.jp/books/detail/00003435